# Copy animation effects from another ppt file to my current selected shape

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint, shapes

The below code runs but gives out error "Please select a shape in the current presentation", even if its selected,

i was expecting it to copy animation of sourceshape(from another file) & apply it to current selected shape

```
Option Explicit


Sub CopyAnimationFromSource()
    Dim sourcePPT As Presentation
    Dim sourceSlide As Slide
    Dim sourceShape As Shape
    Dim targetShape As Shape
    Dim sourcePath As String  ' Define the sourcePath variable

    ' Set the path to your source PowerPoint file
    sourcePath = "F:\MAs work\copy.pptx"
    
    ' Open the source PowerPoint file
    Set sourcePPT = Presentations.Open(sourcePath)
    
    ' Ensure a shape is selected in the current presentation
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
        Set targetShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a shape in the current presentation."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set the source slide and shape from the source presentation
    Set sourceSlide = sourcePPT.Slides(1) ' Change slide number as needed
    Set sourceShape = sourceSlide.Shapes("SourceShapeName") ' Replace with the name of your source shape
    
    ' Copy animation effects from source shape to target shape
    CopyAnimations sourceShape, targetShape
    
    ' Close the source presentation
    sourcePPT.Close
End Sub

Sub CopyAnimations(sourceShape As Shape, targetShape As Shape)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sourceEffect As AnimationEffect
    Dim targetEffect As AnimationEffect
    
    ' Clear animations on the target shape
    targetShape.AnimationSettings.AnimationOrder = 1
    For Each targetEffect In targetShape.AnimationSettings.AnimationEffects
        targetEffect.Delete
    Next targetEffect
    
    ' Copy animations from the source shape to the target shape
    For Each sourceEffect In sourceShape.AnimationSettings.AnimationEffects
        i = i + 1
        Set targetEffect = targetShape.AnimationSettings.Add(sourceEffect.PresetEffect, sourceEffect.Shape)
        targetEffect.MoveTo i
    Next sourceEffect
End Sub
```